# How can I replicate the home screen dots?

Tags: android, user-interface

On Android, the home screen has dots to indicate which screen you are on. I want to do something similar in my app. Is there a control that contains dots and lights up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No... you will have to do it by your self. Take a look at the Tweetdeck app fro android... they have something similar.